# Many bookmark icons changed in Chrome; how to efficiently change them back?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, bookmarks

Days ago, I had many bookmark icons changed in this way:  [image]
Then I followed Synetech's advice at [How to refresh bookmark favicons in chrome](https://superuser.com/a/376292/364367) and that worked to correct the bookmark icons at the sites I revisited.

If I open each website, I get the correct icon again.  If it's already bookmarked with the strange icon, I delete it and save it again.  But, I have hundreds of bookmarked websites.  Therefore, I'm looking for a way to get all correct icons back.

Is there a more efficient way to do this than manually revisiting every one of those websites?

Comment: The question is pretty clear, and the answer is that you have to visit all of the pages. You can load all of your bookmarks at once by right-clicking on your favorites bar and selecting one of the top options in the context menu.

Comment: @music2myear,sorry but I'm not an expert.To better understand,first I have to visit all hundreds webpages and then right-click on the favorite bar?Because,I tried to right-click on the favorite bar and I choosed the first option " open all(3) " but it didn't load all bookmarks.I mean that many icons are not yet correct.Why?

Comment: They are not correct because the action you performed in the linked post removes Chrome's memory of the icons, so you have to revisit the pages in order for Chrome to GET the new icons. Right-click and Open All... is an option that MIGHT work, but it is just a possible method to visit all of your bookmarked sites to get their correct favicons. However, the solution is to visit all of the websites again in order to get those icons.

Comment: @music2myear,In some websites the icon does not want to change,I mean its always the strange one.What to do?