# Chrome bookmark icons not displaying?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Suddenly my Chrome bookmark icons are not displaying, just the globe is displaying as an icon and not the company logo/image. Any ideas?

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA4G9.png)

p.s Already tried a reinstall.

Comment: If you visit one of the bookmarks, does the icon refresh?

Comment: Nope, I know what you mean. This has worked in the past, but not anymore. @Moab

Comment: Weird, I know when I import bookmarks it does that but they refresh when I visit each site., chrome stores icons in a separate file. I don't think chrome deletes everything during an uninstall, you may have to do that manually.

Comment: @Moab Strange one, but thanks for the help appreciate that :) Hopefully someone may have seen this issue before.

Comment: Will be a short of helpful : https://superuser.com/questions/375321/how-to-refresh-bookmark-favicons-in-chrome